# why @track list doesn't rerender after value is changed?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, es6

i have a list of sobject that is retrieved from the db thanks a call to an apex method tha return the list, the list is retrived async with a the setInterval function .

```
 //this is the sample of the html code
      <div class="toast-body">
        <ul>

            <li class="item"  for:each={notifiche} for:item="n" key={n.Id}>
                <img class="icon"  style="margin-left: 10px;">{n.Message__c} 
            </li>

        </ul>
      </div>


/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
 import {
  LightningElement,
  api,
  track,
  wire
 } from 'lwc';
 import resourceName from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/portale';
 import {
  loadStyle,
  loadScript
 } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'; 

import getNotifiche from '@salesforce/apex/homePageLWCController.getNotifiche';  

export default class Header extends LightningElement {


@track notifiche = []
init(){
  console.log(' init');
  this.notifiche =[];
  getNotifiche({recordId:Id})
        .then(res1 => {

            console.log(res1);

            this.notifiche= res1;  /// this work 
        });

  // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation
  setInterval(function(){

    getNotifiche({recordId:Id})
        .then(res1 => {
            console.log(res1);
            this.notifiche = null;
            this.notifiche= res1;  /// this doesn't work 



        });
    }
  ,3000);  

}


}
```

when the init is the executed the first time the reactive variable notifiche is populated correctly, but when i tried to  populate from the setInterval the list notifiche doesn't rerender , i check whith the log and the list that is return from the apex is correct .
How can i cause a rerender of this list ? 
Is correct to assign this variable with @track ? 
Any solutions ?

Comment: Is "homePageLWCController.getNotifiche" marked as cachable?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can use the for each directive on anything but a template tag. The documentation says: To render a list of items, use for:each directive or the iterator directive to iterate over an array. Add the directive to a nested <template> tag that encloses the HTML elements you want to repeat. See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_lists

Comment: Try passing this.notifiche into the setInterval() as a parameter. When you call "this" within the setInterval() you're actually in a different scope, so this.notifiche doesn't point to the top-level variable. Do setInterval( function(n){},3000,this.notifiche);    Then replace your references to this.notifiche in your setInterval with references to the "n" var.

Comment: @PhilW tht apex method is marked as cacheable=false.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is almost certainly due to the callback function on setInterval not having "this" bound to the LWC component instance, plus the need to scope the usage of "getNotifiche" to the LWC component instance:

```
setInterval(function () {
    this.getNotifiche({recordId:Id})
        .then(res1 => {
            console.log(res1);
            this.notifiche = null;
            this.notifiche= res1;  /// this doesn't work 
        });
    }.bind(this), 3000);
```

Without [this binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function (not being an arrow function) defines its own "[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)" (the window instance calling the function).

Comment: this bind doesn't work, in fact when the Init() start the first time with the line marked as 'this work' the list is populated. The first time that was populated the list by the setInterval the list is set to null , i also try to remove the line 'this.notifiche=null' but the result doesn't changee

Comment: There was a missing use of "this" to reference "getNotifiche" as well. Both the binding and this.getNotifiche are required.

Comment: can you provide more  detail or an example ? i tried with `setInterval(function () {
    this.getNotifiche({recordId:Id})
        .then(res1 => {
            console.log(res1);
            this.notifiche = null;
            this.notifiche= res1;  /// this doesn't work 
        });
    }.bind(this,this.getNotifiche), 3000);`  but doesn't work it return Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Comment: Remove the second parameter in the binding. I already updated the answer with the detail.

Comment: Nothing, doesn't work . i tried also with 'refreshApex(this.notifiche)' and to pass 'this.notifiche' as parameter on the setInterval function ...

Comment: OK, so you used it with exactly the code I have in the answer and it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I copy exactly your code

Comment: OK. I have no idea why this didn't sort the issue out for you. Perhaps someone can point out my mistake?

Comment: Try passing a reference to the LWC variable into the setInterval() method per my comment above. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457826/pass-parameters-in-setinterval-function

Comment: This is, I believe, simply the same as using a binding for "this" here, just without the need to explicitly pass an alias for "this".

Comment: @NicholasZozaya can you provide me an example more detailed ? please . Casue i tried to pass 'this' as variable and it doesnt'work .